# Combinatorial Avatar of Irrep Dimensions Dividing the Order of the Group

Tags: co.combinatorics, gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory

Suppose $G$ is a finite group and $V$ a complex irreducible representation. Let $v\in V$ be a sufficiently generic vector, and consider its orbit, $O(v)=\{gv|g\in G\}$. As a naive attempt to combinatorially see the fact that $\dim V$ divides $|G|$ one may ask

> **Question:** Can $O(v)$ be written as the union of $|G|/\dim V$ bases of $V$?

If this is not always true, are there conditions on $G$ that can make the answer positive?

Comment: You seem to be assuming that $O\left(v\right)$ consists of $\left|G\right|$ elements, but this is only true (in a literal sense) if $V$ is faithful. Maybe some counting-with-multiplicities is needed here (i.e., regard $O\left(v\right)$ as a family, not a set, and then decompose the indexing set $G$).

Comment: @darij I agree, in general it's best thought of as a multiset partition problem.

Comment: Interesting question! In order to attempt to prove $\dim V\mid\lvert G\rvert$ this way, we may replace $G$ with its homomorphic image in $\text{GL}(V)$. Thus without loss of generality, $G$ acts faithfully.